# Google chrome takes 1.1 gb of memory to download and load a large image (24000x12000) of size 17.2 mb

Tags: image, google-chrome, memory-management, browser, v8

How does google chrome browser internally work while downloading and processing images?

When one tries to open [this image](https://www.mapsland.com/maps/world/large-scale-detailed-satellite-map-of-the-world.jpg) then *google chrome task manager* shows 1.1 GB of memory footprint(do make sure you use ***disabled cache*** while replication)
[image: While loading large image, memory footprint]

After the image is downloaded and loaded then the memory is released and it drops to 77 MB of memory footprint
[image: After image load and download]

I couldn't figure out any reason for such high memory consumption. Neither what chrome internally does that consumes such huge memory.

I'm looking for any relevant answer or blog which can help me understand the internal architecture or design which guides chrome to behave such a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG is a compressed image storage format. For displaying the image, an application has to uncompress it in memory. A reasonable expectation is 4 bytes per pixel (one byte for each color channel), so your image takes 24000*12000*4 bytes = 1.07 GB.

Comment: Sounds logical. Can you share any blog or document for more detailed read on this topic?

Comment: Which topic, precisely? Image compression? Here's a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression

Comment: The browser part. How does browser render images or other multimedia elements which causes such high memory consumption?

Comment: This is not specific to browsers. Viewing images requires uncompressing them in memory. See e.g. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/windows-photo-viewer-ram-usage-over-1gb/a537b195-4ae8-4bcf-90ac-37e0399efae5.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for clarifying it.